# Why do people study unbounded derived category of quasi-coherent sheaves rather than focus on bounded derived category of coherent sheaves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, big-picture, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a scheme and let $D_{qoch}(X)$ and $D^b_{coh}(X)$ be the unbounded derived category of quasi-coherent sheaves and bounded derived category of coherent sheaves on $X$, respectively.

$D^b_{coh}(X)$ is closely related to the geometry of $X$ and has been intensively studied, see for example [Huybrechts's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199296863). On the other hand, $D_{qcoh}(X)$ has also been studied but its categorical structure is more complicated. For example, the injective resolutions in $D_{qcoh}(X)$ are actually h-injective complexes and more difficult to construct than the injective resolutions $D^b_{coh}(X)$.

My question is: is there any place that $D_{qcoh}(X)$ rather than $D^b_{coh}(X)$ plays an essential role? By "essential" I mean that $D_{qcoh}(X)$ is more than just an auxiliary tool.

Comment: Certain functors do not necessarily restrict to the bounded derived category. That's a pretty important reason to consider the unbounded derived category if you ask me.

Comment: @pbelmans Among the Grothendieck's six functors, it seems that the pushforward does not exist in the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The underlying $\infty$-category of $D_{qcoh}(X)$ is presentable, but the underlying $\infty$-category of $D_{qcoh}^b(X)$ is not (it doesn't have all limits and colimits).

Comment: The push-forward may take complexes of coherent sheaves to complexes of quasi-coherent sheaves.  The pull-back may take bounded complexes to unbounded ones.

Comment: Remember, [it is better to have a good category with bad objects, than a bad category with good objects](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133020/what-is-the-source-of-this-famous-grothendieck-quote).

Comment: Sometimes, starting from a very geometric situation one has to take homotopy limits and colimits which are no longer in $D_{coh}(X)$. A natural example of this is when considering Cartier modules. See Thm. 1.3.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.2996.pdf for an example with nice geometric consequences where I do not know how to prove the result in $D_{coh}(X)$.